# Thymeleaf custom dialect - nested attributes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I would like to ask if it is possible to have nested attributes in HTML tag which can reuse result of previous one. For example

```
<p custom:one="some text to process" custom:two="process result of custom:one">
```

where `custom:one` can be used standalone but `custom:two` have to be used with `custom:one`. The final result will be produced by `custom:two`

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, you can do it with [local variables](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables)

You need to specify **th:with** to declare a variable.

Note that the declared variable is available within the element.

```
<div th:with="newValue = 'Hello ' + ${val}">
  <span th:text="${val}">One</span>
  <span th:text="${newValue}>Two</span>
</div>
```

Let me know if that's what you're looking for.